# Center UIView in container without jumping

Tags: swift, uiview, tableview, constraints, collectionview

I have this structure:

- container (UIView)

  - Header (UIView)
  - TableView

    - CollectionView
    - CollectionView
    - CollectionView

When a favorite button is pressed I want a view to be displayed on top of everything and to be centered. Whenever it is added when the tableView has not been scrolled, it works fine. However, when added after it has been scrolled the whole layout kind of jumps into place. The more scroll, the more jumping. Visual representation of the layout:

https://gyazo.com/8ddc75ce1ac96ff00aa9a9d8b0d4b725

The view is loaded from a xib and centered in its container. The view height and width anchors are already set (and translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false). Here is the configure method of the view to be centered.

```swift
public func configure(viewToCenterItselfInside: UIView) {
        self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToCenterItselfInside.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToCenterItselfInside.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.alpha = 1
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(1500)) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.alpha = 0
            }) { (_) in
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code when the view is loaded

```swift
if let addedFavorite = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ConfirmationView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? ConfirmationView {
            view.addSubview(addedFavorite)
            addedFavorite.configure(viewToCenterItselfInside: view)
        }
```

In addition to trying to solve it with constraints I've also tried centering it using self.center = viewToCenterItselfInside and messing around with the UIScreen.main without any results. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't be any issue if this view is not added to `tableView` by any means.

Comment: So what do you think is the problem? I’m adding it to the ViewControllers view (the container view I outlined)